# How to check for specific collision points

Tags: c#

I am developing a small ping-pong game for C#. I have the general idea on how to do collisions, however I am having difficulties specifying specific locations on the paddle.

I have a ball which bounces around the form (bounces off the walls), and it can also bounce off the paddle. However, when it bounces off the paddle it always bounces off at the same angle.

What I would like to do is specify sections of the paddle (e.g, left corner, right corner, middle), and based on where it hits the paddle I want to change the angle.

If anyone could help me figure out how to specify sections of a control (in this case a picture box), I would greatly appreciate it.

Edit: Sorry, I believe I haven't been very clear. What I want to know is how can I check WHERE the ball hits the paddle.

I won't be implementing any fancy physics based angle reflection, I'll simply be assigning direct values.

I know you can use ball.Bounds.IntersectsWith(paddle.bounds), but that is just any collision. Is it possible to specify something like 'intersects with left edge, right edge' or etc?

Again, sorry for the confusion.

Edit 2: Hopefully this will clear some of things up, here's my code for bouncing off the paddle as of current. The paddle is just one picture box, and the 'ball', is just an image inside a picturebox.

**pcbPluto is the 'ball'.

```
        //bounce off user/ai paddles 
        if (this.pcbPluto.Bounds.IntersectsWith(this.pcbUser.Bounds))
        {
            //if it hits user's paddle, reverse y direction
            intDirectionY *= -1;
        }
        else if (this.pcbPluto.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pcbComputer.Bounds))
        {
            //if it hits computer's paddle, reverse direction
            intDirectionY *= -1; 
        }
```

As you can see, as of current upon hitting either the user or computer's paddle, I just reverse the vertical movement. The problem with this is that the angle is static regardless of where the ball hits the paddle.

What I would like to do is make it so that if the ball hits certain areas of the paddle, the angle would be different. For example, if it hits the edges, it might go out at a steeper angle, if it hits the middle sections, perhaps an angle of 30 etc.

Again, sorry for the confusion.

Last Edit: Got it working! Below is the method that I used to specify 'where' the ball hit the picturebox, and based on that I changed the angle of reflection.

```
public void AiBallBouncer()
    {
        //variable declaration and assignment
        double dblComputerRelativeLocation = 0;

        dblComputerRelativeLocation = Math.Abs((((double)pcbComputer.Left - (double)pcbAsteroid.Left) / (double)pcbAsteroid.Width));

        //check for if the ball bounces on the paddles
        if (pcbAsteroid.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pcbComputer.Bounds))
        {
            //check for which angle of reflection to use 

            if (dblComputerRelativeLocation <= 0.1)
            {
                //reverse direction
                intDirectionY *= -1;

                //set new angle 
                intAngle = 30;

                //increase speed 
                intSpeed += 2;
            }
            else if (dblComputerRelativeLocation <= 0.2)
            {
                //reverse direction 
                intDirectionY *= -1;

                //set new angle 
                intAngle = 35;
            }
            else if (dblComputerRelativeLocation <= 0.4)
            {
                //reverse direction
                intDirectionY *= -1;

                //set new angle 
                intAngle = 50;

                //set speed back to normal
                intSpeed = 5;
            }
            else if (dblComputerRelativeLocation <= 0.6)
            {
                //reverse direction
                intDirectionY *= -1;

                //set new angle 
                intAngle = 60;

                //set speed back to normal
                intSpeed = 5;
            }
            else if (dblComputerRelativeLocation <= 0.8)
            {
                //reverse direction
                intDirectionY *= -1;

                //set new angle 
                intAngle = 50;
            }
            else if (dblComputerRelativeLocation <= 0.9)
            {
                //reverse direction
                intDirectionY *= -1;

                //set new angle 
                intAngle = 35;
            }
            else if (dblComputerRelativeLocation <= 1.0)
            {
                //reverse direction
                intDirectionY *= -1;

                //set new angle 
                intAngle = 30;

                //increase speed 
                intSpeed += 2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can do it mathematically, were you take the angle the ball has right before collision and change it based on angle of incidence. With complete reflection you will simply take 180 degrees - that angle.

Comment: check this stack exchange post out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/how-do-you-calculate-where-a-ball-should-go-when-it-bounces-off-the-bar

Comment: It is definitely not a programming question, it belongs to physics/math forum. Once you have the formula, try to implement it. If you have any specific problem with your implementation, come back here.

Comment: What sort of help are you looking for? You haven't made it clear how your code works and detects collisions in the first place. I would imagine that if you can conclude that it collides that it shouldn't be too hard to confirm where it collides. However without code showing what you've done (or at least pseudocode or more details) I'm not sure what we can do. For example what is the ball? What is the bat? As a final thought could you make your bat a composite of three objects that are glued together and then check for collisions with each part...

Answer (score 0):

I could say when developing a game, priority goes to "looks right" and "feels right", not mathematical correctness (for example if you get a rendered shape, from graphic cards of two identical play boxes - whatever they are - you will see the green shadows that seem exactly like each other, are actually different in some bits; and shapes are not mathematically identical).

So instead of find exact collision point and try to categorize it; (just a suggestion) just divide the paddle into a grid (I would say a 7x7 would be more than enough; and choose odd number) and categorize those parts as left edge, right edge, etc. Naturally some squares would be excluded.